# Eclipse git plugin, tag double click

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin

Im a bit new on Eclipse and git. Happend to double click on my latest TAG. See screen shot.
What does the black/white marker mean and how can I get rid of it without damaging my TAG?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little black marker means that you're currently checking out that branch.

Best EGit tutorial, [right here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

My suggestion is you allocate a Saturday afternoon, and follow this tutorial carefully. By the end of the day, you'll be a damn pro with EGit. :) Good luck.

Comment: Great Thanks! Have been avoiding it so far:-)

Comment: Don't avoid it, embrace it. If you know you're gonna use EGit a lot in the future, it's best to document yourself properly, and not work blindly with it.